# How do I display a query result in listboxes?

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, t-sql

I have a database with entities `AuthorId` (int) (AuthorId is the primary key), `Name`(nvarchar) and `Nationality`(nvarchar). I also have a listbox, which displays the names from that database, and three textboxes where I want to display the Id, Name and Nationality, one for each textbox, of the selected item in the listbox. With what I have it now I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.

Here's how I get the data and display it in the listbox:

```
public void GetAuthorData()
{
    string connectionString = //connection string here
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Author";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Author a = new Author();
                a.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                a.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                a.Nationality = reader.GetString(2);

                AuthorListBox.Items.Add(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I display the data in the textboxes:

```
private void AuthorListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DeleteAuthortButton.IsEnabled = true;
    SaveChangesButton.IsEnabled = true;

    var aa = sender as ListBox;
    if (aa.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       var author = aa.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string connectionString = //connection string here
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Author where Name = '" + author + "'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Author a = new Author();
                    a.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    a.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                    a.Nationality = reader.GetString(2);

                    IdTextBox.Text = a.Id.ToString();
                    AuthorNameTextBox.Text = a.Name;
                    NationalityTextBox.Text = a.Nationality;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a.Id = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);`

Comment: You already setting Author to List Item so use it... `var author = aa.SelectedItem as Author;` and you don't need to select anything from DB again.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I get "cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'int' " when i use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to retrieve database data. All the information about the author is in the list.

```
    private void AuthorListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteAuthortButton.IsEnabled = true;
        SaveChangesButton.IsEnabled = true;

        var aa = sender as ListBox;
        if (aa.SelectedItem != null)
        {
           var author = aa.SelectedItem as Author;

           IdTextBox.Text = author.Id.ToString();
           AuthorNameTextBox.Text = author.Name;
           NationalityTextBox.Text = author.Nationality; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql `Number` doesn't necessary corresponds to .Net `int`:

```
      a.Id = reader.GetInt32(0); // May fail even if Id is Number
```

Try using `Convert`:

```
      // Whatever Author.Id is 
      // (e.g. Number(10) which will be mapped to Int64, not int or
      //       Number(30) which can be mapped to String), 
      // try convert it into `Int32 == int`
      a.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
      a.Name = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
      a.Nationality = Convert.ToString(reader[2]);
```

Comment: Well i didnt get any error message but it didnt print out anything in the textboxes.

Comment: @anek05: do you have `AuthorListBox` properly filled?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with properly filled? I have three items in the database that prints out in the listbox if that's what you mean

Comment: The `public void GetAuthorData()` fills `AuthorListBox` list box: `... AuthorListBox.Items.Add(a); ...` do you have it has been filled?

Comment: Put a *breakpoint* at `var query = "SELECT * FROM Author where Name = '" + author + "'";` what is `author` value you put into `where`?

Comment: Before I had `AuthorListBox.Items.Add(a.name) but instead i changed it and use DisplayMemberpatch `Name`

Comment: `author` have the value `SQLLabb1.Author`

Comment: And so you have `SELECT * FROM Author where Name = 'SQLLabb1.Author'` query and since there are *no authors* with `SQLLabb1.Author` Name in the database, you have nothing to put into `TextBox`es

Comment: I might missunderstand you. But i have three rows/authors in the database. Might be wrong with this aswell but shouldnt the query be `SELECT * FROM Author where AuthorId = 'SQLLabb1.Author` (as AuthorId is the primary key?)

Comment: You're building the query with `var query = "SELECT * FROM Author where Name = '" + author + "'";` command; if `author` is in fact `"SQLLabb1.Author"` string, the final query will be `SELECT * FROM Author where Name = 'SQLLabb1.Author'`; when RDMBS executes the query it'll not find any record with such a weird name. `reader.Read()` retrun `false` (empty cursor) and you'll have nothing to display.

Comment: This is what i get when i put a breakpoint on the query `Name: author Value:"SQLLabb1.Author" Type: string`

Comment: `author.ToString()` - the very value will be put in the query `SQLLabb1.Author`; check the final `query` value